# How to set jHTMLArea to readonly

Tags: javascript, jhtmlarea

I have used jHTMLArea to create rich text box and have been able to save and edit the same.But while showing the data in view mode.The inner html/data seems to be editable.How to set the jHtmlArea to readonly.

```
<textarea onblur="SaveInfo('Save')" class="txtContentDesc" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder3_txtAreaS11" style="display: none;" readonly="true"></textarea>
```

The following code allows jHTMLArea textbox to be editable.

Comment: If you want the codes to be readonly, why bother to use jHTMLArea? Ignore it and directly insert your edited html/data to an element or iframe.

Comment: User should be able to know that, the field can be formatted to html tags,Hence, it has been suggested to provide the view mode under jHTMLArea

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but here it is:

`domElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false')`